# RequireJS optimize !text Dynamic load not allowed

Tags: requirejs, r.js

I use the plugin `!text`, and want that after optimization by `r.js`, user to edit their own templates. But after optimization I get an error: Dynamic load not allowed.

**build.js**

```
{
    baseUrl: "f/app",
    appDir: "..",
    dir: "dist",
    modules: [
    {
        name: "catalog"
    }
    ],
    stubModules: ['text'],
    optimizeAllPluginResources: false,
    inlineText: false,
    paths: {
        app: '../libs',
        jquery: 'empty:',
        underscore: 'empty:',
        backbone: 'empty:',
        marionette: 'empty:',
        JSON: 'empty:',
        // Plugins
        text: '../libs/rjs-text',
    },
    exclude: ["jquery","underscore","backbone","marionette", 'JSON', 'text']
}
```

This is generally how it is possible to implement?

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way (you're new here, so I'm just trying to explain), but you need to ask better questions if you want people to provide answers.  So far you've given us a long require config with almost no context whatsoever (only two short sentences that actually describe the problem and zero lines of the code that actually causes the problem).  If you edit your question to provide better info, you might get a better response.

Answer (score 1):

Without any example code this is virtually impossible to answer (as I said in my comment).  However, just to take a shot in the dark, *perhaps* your problem is that you're using variables for your require imports, and that is annoying the require optimizer.  Using literal arrays should solve that; in other words don't do:

```
var myDependencies = ['foo', 'bar'];
define(myDependencies, function(...
```

do:

```
define(['foo', 'bar'], function(...
```

See this link on the Require site for more info:

http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html